# Excel text data import Step 3 select columns via keyboard on Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I am experiencing the following issue in Microsoft Excel for Mac 2016. When using the `From Text` data import function and clicking through the first two steps (selecting "Delimited" and defining delimiter), [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTBWv.png) allows for changing the column data format. By default, column 1 is selected and I can click to select any other column that fits into the window, as shown in the screenshot below. However, it seems that it is not possible to select columns that are to the right of those visible in the window. In my example below, there are about four more columns to the right. Scrolling and arrow-keys seem to not work in the Mac version.

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or some other workaround, that I am missing?

[image: Sreenshot of step in text import I am referring to]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a two-finger touch (not a complete tap), more like a contact. A slider bar will appear at the bottom of the columns. Now is your chance to grab it with one-finger click. If you begin with the pointer in the bottom part of the columns, it is much easier to grab the slider as it should be under the pointer. This probably works on other such windows.

Comment: Thank you. Worst UI ever made probably.